# Mystery WiFi network shows up when laptop is connected

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

When my laptop, a Dell XPS 15 (9530), is connected to my WiFi network, a new network with the SSID "DIRECT-IE[laptop name]msSP", where "[laptop name]" is replaced with the name of the computer.

Interestingly, this network is on the same channel as the network to which the laptop is connected, and this changes if I change the channel setting on the router.

The effect persists even if the hotspot feature on the laptop is turned off, and only appears when it is connected to a network.

I was wondering whether this is some kind of WiFi Direct feature, but it does not appear when I search for WiFi direct-enabled devices using my smartphone.

UPDATE: In Task Manager, two network connections are shown, one being the normal connection. However, the other, with no activity, is labelled "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3", with the SSID listed the same as the aforementioned cryptic network name. It appears Windows thinks it is connected to the network originating from this very computer.

[image]

Comment: Possible clue - MSSP is managed security services provider?

Comment: Isn't MSSP an ISP-level thing?

Comment: Then I don't see how it's relevant.

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure I'm right but if not, could you add your windows version (and build!) you your question?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Its related to screen casting - which uses miracast and wifi direct. The feature is called "[Projecting to this PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15053/windows-8-project-wireless-screen-miracast)" and found under "connect" in the action center . Its a new feature with windows 10 anniversary update, and lets you use miracast to send the output from one system to another (works with my android marshmallow android phone as well, to an arbitrary system).

Turning it off and on makes that device appear and disappear.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Turning off this wifi does seem to save battrey.