# How to "connect" a wifi direct adapter?

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, cmd.exe

After executing `ipconfig /all` in cmd, I get that the `Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter` is  `Media State . . .: Media disconnected`. How do I "connect" it? I didn't (intentionally, at least) disconnect anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. [Wifi Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct) is mainly used for things like miracast. Its probably using the newish virtual wifi adapter option.

I discovered if the screen casting option is on (aka project to this PC) [this device appears](https://superuser.com/a/1162441/10165), and it disappears when you remove it.

There may be some other uses for this (printers? Cameras?) but I suspect it should be used as needed rather than connected to automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable/configure Wireless Hosted Network?

**About the Wireless Hosted Network**:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243(v=vs.85).aspx

If so, please check below confirmations:
1.  Open Network and Sharing Center - Change Adapter settings, right click the Wi-Fi network adapter and open Properties – Sharing – select Allow other network users to connect…Internet connection – in the drop down under Home networking connection, pick the name of the virtual Wi-Fi adapter.
2.  Device Manager – Network Adapters – your Wi-Fi network adapter properties - Power Management - Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2863207/wi-fi-direct-wfd-may-not-be-available-after-suspend-resume-on-windows

If problem persists, please provide screenshots of below information:
1.  Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Change Adapter settings.
2.  “Ipconfig /all“ complete result.
3.  Device Manager – Network Adapters (click View to show hidden devices).

Best Regards,
Eve Wang

Comment: Actually, its completely unrelated, and somewhat unintuitive to work out - wifi direct is used by miracast and some cameras for fast wireless data transfer over wifi, without being part of a infrastructure network. Its pretty neat but you arn't actually using windows as a AP